# What is a good word for someone who "gets the joke"?

Tags: adjectives

Grandmother recently passed, I'm having a hard time with adjectives

Edit: She was incredibly smart, witty and quick with words. She was a wiz at puzzles, games and cards. She could remember long passages of books. I just can't seem to find the right adjectives to describe her.

Comment: I'm sorry for your loss, but can you provide some more context information to your question please, and a sample sentence?

Comment: She had a quick mind, a remarkable memory, and a wonderful sense of humo[u]r.

Comment: When someone **doesn't** get a joke, you could say that it went over their head.  So perhaps you could say "She was quick - no joke ever went over her head." or something along those lines.

Comment: Also, "quick on the uptake".

Comment: It sounds like she was **sharp** or had a **sharp mind**.

Answer (score 3):

If your grandmother had keen mental perception and understanding of those things you mentioned, I would say your granny was **"perspicacious"**

> - [**perspicacious**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perspicacious) - (adjective) "having or showing an ability to notice and understand things that are difficult or not obvious"

e.g.

- "She was much too **perspicacious** to be taken in by such a spurious argument."
- "The **perspicacious** plumber quickly detected the leakage."
- "Although my mom was a **perspicacious** woman, she was not able to understand why my brother had lied.

> - **[perspicacity](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/perspicacity)** (noun) "the ability to understand things quickly and make accurate judgments"
>
>   "Grandma was a woman of exceptional **perspicacity**."